# How can I establish the difference between two HEX colours?

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, less

I need to be able to extract the different between two hex colours, represented itself as a hex colour, in order to combine them at a later point using LESS.

Ideally, this would work in javascript

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to combine the colors?

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly do you have problems with? Hexadecimal is just a number representation, so performing subtraction should not be the problem.

Comment: It's not, though. It's three pairs.

Comment: By combine, I mean add them together. Less allows you to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a full Javascript solution :

```
function parseHexColor(c) {
  var j = {};

  var s = c.replace(/^#([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$/, function(_, r, g, b) {
    j.red = parseInt(r, 16);
    j.green = parseInt(g, 16);
    j.blue = parseInt(b, 16);

    return "";
  });

  if(s.length == 0) {
    return j;
  }
};

function colorDifference(a, b) {
  var a = parseHexColor(a);
  var b = parseHexColor(b);

  if(typeof(a) != 'undefined' && typeof(b) != 'undefined') {
    return "#" + (a.red - b.red).toString(16) + (a.green - b.green).toString(16) + (a.blue - b.blue).toString(16);
  }
};
```

Try yourself :

```
colorDifference('#FFFFFF', '#AABBCC'); // returns : "#554433"
```

Comment: The name of the `colorToJson` function is misleading. It does not create JSON.

Comment: Totally agree, feel free to rewrite function names :)

Comment: I would suggest adding `Math.abs` to your color subtractions to ensure you don't get a value like `#-ff-ff-ff`

Answer (score 1):

In LESS you can safely perform calculations on colors, so combining two is easy as this:

```
{
    color: #ff0000 + #00ff00;
}
```

or even

```
{
    color: red + green;
}
```

EDIT:

Similarly you are able to get the difference between two colors by mere subtracting them and storing the difference in a LESS variable for later.

```
@difference: #ffff00 - #ff0000;
```

should give you `#00ff00` as a result.

Comment: I get that, which is why I need to work backwards from the colours I have. Say I need to add colours x and y to make colour z. I have the values for X and Z