# color code to closest color available

Tags: jquery, color-picker, color-codes

I am trying to use any of the  jquery color picker available. When user selects a color, I have to match it with closest color available and query the db.
Question would be, for a given color code, how will i match it with the nearest color code from my list of available colors?

Comment: See [Color difference/similarity% between two values with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586999/color-difference-similarity-between-two-values-with-js)

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the available colors are from the color picker and what "your available colors" are.

Comment: whoo. Thank you. I didn't know color code would be that complicated. I think I ll choose an alternative solution like image map.