# Comparing two colors to get likeness rating

Tags: javascript, colors

I have a color selector that allows a user to change fore and background color for a grid. I wondered if there is a way to compare two colors in the #FFFFFF format to get a "likeness" rating, i.e. to try and verify if the foreground colors are readable on a specified background.

Comment: There is, you can compute the Euclidean distance between the colors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586999/color-difference-similarity-between-two-values-with-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `colour_1 = #aabbcc` and `colour_2 = #AABBCC` you could do something like:

```
diff = sqrt((aa - AA)^2 + (bb - BB)^2 + (cc - CC)^2)
```

The smaller this value is, the more alike the two colours should be.