# Hex Code Difference

Tags: javascript, colors, less

Is it possible to calculate the difference between two hex codes? I have been searching for hours and I'm starting to think it's not possible.

Example:
Color #1: `#c60f13`
Color #2: `#970b0e`
Difference: `25% Darker`

Oh yeah, I came across a Javascript calculator, but it didn't work.

Thanks guys!

Comment: This question can help you a bit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820655/how-can-i-establish-the-difference-between-two-hex-colours

Comment: That's the script I was talking about. For some odd reason, it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate them into (3) 2-byte groups, do the math for each group individually and apply that to the color that the group represents (Red / Green / Blue).

```
C6 - 97 = red diff
0F - 0B = green diff
13 - 03 = blue diff
```

Comment: Awesome! Will definitely try this out.

Comment: The difference is #2f45. Let's say I want to make color #1 lighter by #2f45, how would that work?

Answer (score 1):

**HEX numbers and HEX RGB colors are not equal**.
However they are both numbers, HEX representation of RGB values contains 3 independent components: Red, Green and Blue, packed as 3x8bit components like #RRGGBB. This way we can store them as a single integer.

First you need to unpack the individual components, this way:

```
r = (HEX >> 16) & 0xFF
g = (HEX >> 8)  & 0xFF
b =  HEX        & 0xFF
```

Now you can perform the calculations

```
_r = abs(r1 - r2)
_g = abs(g1 - g2)
_b = abs(b1 - b2)
```

then repack them:

```
HEX = _r<<16 | _g<<8 | _b
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the resulting color value of the difference. Also, because you tagged this with a [less](/questions/tagged/less) tag, I am going to assume your are using the [less css preprocessor](http://www.lesscss.org/), and if so, it already has a function for this: `difference()`. So it is just this:

```
difference(#c60f13, #970b0e);
```

Which produces this:

```
#2f0405
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract them directly as hexadecimal values.

```
  0xc60f13
- 0x970b0e
----------
= 0x2F0405
```

If you first split them up in groups you would get the same result:

```
  c6   0f   13
 -97  -0b  -0e
 -------------
 =2F  =04  =05
```

So there is no need to do this first.

In JavaScript you can this calculation like this:

```
var val1 = 0xc60f13;
var val2 = 0x970b0e;
var diff = (val1 - val2) & 0xffffff;

console.log(diff.toString(16));
```

Result:

```
2f0405
```